# how to create prev/next links in dreamweaver for spry

Tags: dreamweaver, spry

anyone know a good way to create prev/next links in dreamweaver for spry datasets?
I can do it with normal datasets but not spry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although question is old and SPRY is no longer supported by Adobe (and I cannot understand exactly the meaning of the phrase normal datasets but not spry) I think that you can use
the http://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/data_region/PagingSample.html   as a reference for creating next prev links.